# Elif and Else Issue in Python 3

Tags: if-statement, python-3.x

Just practicing my Python skills and I'm trying to write a program that converts letters into certain numbers which I specify. This part of the code gives me an error. I know it's probably something really minor which I will feel stupid about asking when you guys point me to the problem.

Here's the code:

```
num = input("Number is:")
    for digit in num:
        if (digit == "a" or "b" or "c"):
            digit = "2"
        elif (digit == "d" or "e" or "f"):
            digit = "3"
        elif (digit == "g" or "h" or "i"):
            digit = "4"     
        elif (digit == "j" or "k" or "l"):
            digit = "5"
        elif (digit == "m" or "n" or "o"):
            digit = "6"
        elif (digit == "p" or "q" or "r" or "s"):
            digit = "7"
        elif (digit == "t" or "u" or "v"):
            digit = "8"
        else (digit == "w" or "x" or "y" or "z"):
            digit = "9"
```

Error given: "Syntax Error:     else (digit == "w" or "x" or "y" or "z"):: None, line 1710".

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `digit == 'w' or 'x'` is ambiguous the way you're treating it. Does it mean `(digit == 'w') or ('x')`, or does it mean `digit == ('w' or 'x')` (which still won't work, but assume it does). You need to be explicit: `digit == 'w' or digit == 'x'`, or more concisely: `digit in ('w', 'x')`.

Answer (score 3):

The [else](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) does not take a conditional. If you want to narrow your `digit=9` to `w`, `x`, `y` or `z`, then you need to make that an `elif` as well.

Otherwise,

```
else:
    digit = "9"
```

Reading further into your code, your conditionals are not complete. A better way to do these checks

```
if digit in ["a", "b", "c"]:
```

Or, to be closer inline with how your code is now:

```
if digit == "a" or digit == "b" or digit == "c":
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the right answer. Now the thing is that it just doesn't convert any letter to it's number. It just keeps the letter. Any idea why ? @andy